# how to convert date format in sqlite (from dd/mm/yy to dd/mm/yyyy) and (d/m/yy to dd/mm/yyyy) in sqlite database

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, formatting

I want to format date in a column where date formats are mixed like d/mm/yy, d/m/yy, dd/mm/yyyy where i want ot format all values should be in one format like mm/dd/yyyy in sqlite database[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reference sqlite db column to use in update statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795043/how-do-i-reference-sqlite-db-column-to-use-in-update-statement)

Comment: Those are just strings with no discernible format or order. [The docs clearly explain](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) that SQLite recognizes *ONLY* the ISO8601 format as a date. With those strings, you can't tell which are `d/m` or `m/d`. For *some* of them, values above 12 suggest the format is `m/d`. For the rest, you can't tell at all.

Comment: You can assume all of those are `m/d/y`, parse them and store them into a separate field with the `YYY-MM-DD` format and check whether your application or calculations work.

Comment: The other problem you have is with the two-digit years. You need to determine where your cutoff will be for 20th or 21st century. Is `9/10/19` the year `2019` or `1919` and is `8/1/20` `2020` or `1920`?

Comment: Thanks @sophros..I have tried it already...

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos...I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not support built-in date and/or time storage class. Instead, it leverages some built-in date and time functions to use other storage classes such as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER for storing the date and time values.

use the TEXT storage class for storing SQLite date and time https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-date/

Comment: That link [and the docs](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) explain that only `YYYY-MM-DD` is recognized. The OP's problem is that none of the strings follows that format

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, should i delete the question?

Comment: @RajeshM no, you should explain what's going on. If you can't re-export the data using the correct format, you'll have to convert somehow. One option could be to copy the data to a new SQLite file, converting the strings in code where possible. If you really have to clean up manually entered data, you have a difficult task ahead. Eg for two-digit years, you may have to guess the correct century based on other data, or your own knowledge of the domain. If you *know* the data comes from the US, you may be able assume the format is always `M/D`

Comment: @RajeshM for example, for `8/7/16`, is there any other information in that record that could help you decide whether that's 1916 or 2016? There's a `1918` date just 3 rows before that, so the string itself is unclear. When converting and copying to a *new* database, you should also record the reason you decided this was 1916 or 2018 along with the original string in two separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

This will convert month, day, year divided by slashes into year, month, day divided by dashes. For example 2/19/1921 into 1921-2-19. Just uses basic SQL with a subquery.

```
SELECT
    surveydate
    ,Substr(dayyear, Instr(dayyear, '/') + 1, 999) || '-' || -- Year
        month || '-' || -- Month
        Substr(dayyear, 0, Instr(dayyear, '/')) -- Day 
    AS surveydate2
FROM (
    SELECT 
        surveydate,
        Substr(surveydate, 0, Instr(surveydate, '/')) AS month,
        Substr(surveydate, Instr(surveydate, '/') + 1, 999) AS dayyear
    FROM "input_locations"
    )
```